# How to make a responsive circle with just CSS?

Tags: html, css

I've made circles with just CSS using percents as the width, but this obviously doesn't work with height as they become ovals. Is there a pure CSS way of doing this?

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far and what code you have?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the .circle class:

```
.circle {
position: relative;
border-radius: 50%;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding-top: 100%;
background: white;
}
```

make sure your padding top is the same as your width and make your height auto.

Comment: I should've been more specific and said concentric circles. I ended up using vw units.
Codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNXYpX